# 0 eigenvalue of weighted laplacian

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I consider (weighted) directed graph and eigenvalues of its laplacian matrix. If a graph contains rooted out-branching which is the subgraph possessing a node can approaching to any nodes in the graph, then laplacian matrix has only one 0 eigenvalue.

The question is "how many multiplicity of 0 eigenvalue of directed laplacian matrix for weakly connected graph does exists" or "how can we identify it".

Answer (score 1):

The rank of Laplacian is $n-\omega(G)$ where $\omega(G)$ is the number of connected components. That is, $\lambda_{n-1}\neq0$ iff the graph is connected.
See [p. 147](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379594904863)